# Sed expression with escape sequence

Tags: linux, sed

I need to replace the string `'../lib' to '/usr/share/server/bootstrap/lib'` in a file bootstrap.sh

I used the following sed expression

```
sed -i -e 's//././/lib///user//share//server//bootstrap//lib/g' bootstrap.sh
```

It fails with the log

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

Unable to identity the mistake in the expression.Kindly help.

Comment: In addition, you seem to be mixing the meaning of forward slashes and backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape every `.` and `/`

```
sed -i -e "s/\.\.\/lib/\/usr\/share\/server\/bootstrap\/lib/" bootstrap.sh
```

Alternative way to avoid two many backslashes using `#` as delimiter instead of `/`.

Thanks [sp asic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sp-asic)

```
sed -i "s#../libs#/usr/share/server/bootstrap/lib#" bootstrap.sh
```

Comment: Thanks.. updated it slightly..sed -i -e "s/\.\.\/lib/\/usr\/share\/server\/bootstrap\/lib/g" bootstrap.sh

Comment: why not use different delimiter and avoid too many backslashes.. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/12280/using-different-delimiters#t=20160729084928666254

Comment: Thanks, updated answer.